# Mocked authentication not applied when using mockMvc together with direct bean access

Tags: spring, spring-security, spock, spring-test, spring-mvc-test

I have an UserRepository annotated with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`. When I perform a mockMvc request, the mocked authentication works as expected. But the repository access afterwards fails with:

```
 An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

Here is my failing test:

```
@WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
def "access repo with security"() {
    expect:
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
        employeeRepository.deleteAll()
        employeeRepository.count() == 0
}
```

This test (without mockMvc) succeeds:

```
@WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
def "access repo with security"() {
    expect:
        employeeRepository.deleteAll()
        employeeRepository.count() == 0
}
```

Can anyone explain me, why it fails after mockMvc?